# Multiple paths for same screen with a single rendering in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a screen with two routes pointing to it. These two routes are in a BottomTabNavigator. My problem is that the target screen is rendered twice. A different rendering for each route.

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={ HomeScreen } options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
<Tab.Screen name="NewProduct" component={ HomeScreen } options={{ title: 'Neues', lazy:false }} />
```

Is there any way to do this without double rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={ HomeScreen } options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="New"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarButton: (props) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={{
            
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            setNewProductInput(true);
            navigation.navigate('Home');
          }}
        >
          <Text>New</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    })}
  />
```